EF Core query translation to single or multiple queries
Is there a way to detect how query is translated from EF Core to SQL Server? I would need to detect if my EF Core query uses AsSplitQuery option and actually translates to multiple SQL queries. For example, if my EF Core expression query is written with AsSplitQuery, but doesn't include any enumerable navigation properties (both in Include nor Select expressions), it will be translated to single SQL query. On the other hand, if EF Core expression query includes enumerable navigation properties (in Include or Select expressions) and uses AsSplitQuery option, it will be translated to multiple SQL queries.

granadaCoder gave a detailed response already, but I just want to add that generated queries are already displayed in output window (in Visual Studio) by default.

If you follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/diagnostic-listeners
and code up a "DiagnosticObserver" as described.
You can look for this "Event-Name".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.coreeventid.queryexecutionplanned?view=efcore-8.0
When I captured the value of this locally on an EF query that had multiple .Include items.. and I explicitly used ".AsSplitQuery()" ..  the below magic string
queryContext => new SplitQueryingEnumerable
showed up.
While it is "magic string" hunting.. I think it could solve your need.
Here is some code.. that is a modified version from the "learn.microsoft" link above.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

namespace MyApp.DomainDataLayer.EntityFramework.Contexts.Listeners;

public class KeyValueObserver : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private static ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> _events = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    public void OnCompleted()
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void OnError(Exception error)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
    {
        if (!_events.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).Contains(value.Key))
        {
            _events.Add(value);
        }

        // if (value.Key == CoreEventId.ContextInitialized.Name)
        // {
        //     ContextInitializedEventData payload = (ContextInitializedEventData) value.Value;
        //     Console.WriteLine($"EF is initializing {payload.Context.GetType().Name} ");
        // }
        //
        // if (value.Key == RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening.Name)
        // {
        //     ConnectionEventData payload = (ConnectionEventData) value.Value;
        //     Console.WriteLine($"EF is opening a connection to {payload.Connection.ConnectionString} ");
        // }
        
        if (value.Key == CoreEventId.QueryExecutionPlanned.Name)
        {
            QueryExpressionEventData payload = (QueryExpressionEventData) value.Value;

            string fullExpressionAsstring = payload.Expression.ToString();
            if (fullExpressionAsstring.Contains("SplitQueryingEnumerable"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"DING DING DING : {fullExpressionAsstring} ");
            }
        }

        string myKeys = string.Join(",", _events.Select(kvp => kvp.Key));
        string temp = string.Empty;
    }
}

Here were my package-references for completeness.
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.*" />

If you find there is something more "isolated" in the QueryExpressionEventData object model.. please add to this SOF post.
Note my "capturing" of _events key names.
In my local code.. the following events-names "fired".
(Aka, the last value of string "myKeys" after my complete request had finished.). "string temp" is just a place for me to set a breakpoint, fyi.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ContextInitialized,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationStarting,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.NavigationBaseIncluded,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryExecutionPlanned,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandCreating,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandCreated,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionOpening,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionOpened,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuting,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuted,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.DataReaderDisposing,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionClosing,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionClosed,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ContextDisposed

UPDATE:
Locally, here is what I see.  Again, "my situation".  But my situation is query against "MyPrimaryEfEntity" (a select with no where/filter) and I am .Include(ing) 2 navigation properties.
WITH :  .AsSplitQuery() (below)
Generated query execution expression: 
'queryContext => new SplitQueryingEnumerable<MyPrimaryEfEntity>(

WITHOUT : .AsSplitQuery() (below)
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryExecutionPlanned, Generated query execution expression: 
'queryContext => new SingleQueryingEnumerable<MyPrimaryEfEntity>(

Note the subtle different between "SplitQueryingEnumerable" and "SingleQueryingEnumerable"

Thank you for your answer. I have tried your proposed solution, however if LINQ query is written with AsSplitQueryoption enabled, it will always get caugth in KeyValueObserver with the following expression (no matter whether it is translated to single or multiple SQL queries/statements): queryContext => new SplitQueryingEnumerable``1(...)

I just retested my scenario.  I updated the end of my answer.  But I am definitely seeing a difference between  "SplitQueryingEnumerable" and "SingleQueryingEnumerable".   Not saying you are.  But I definitely saw a difference.

The problem I have is that LINQ query can be "decorated" with .AsSplitQuery() method when you're not including/selecting enumerable navigation properties. In that case, there will be only one generated SQL query, but LINQ query will still have SplitQueryingEnumerable execution expression. However, I really appreciate and thank you very much for your effort and help.

You can use some internal EF Core functions to do this. These are all public classes, but are documented subject to change in new EF Core builds at any time.
The steps here are as follows:

Cast the DbContext as IInfrastructure and use it to get a IQueryCompilationContextFactory.
Use that to create a RelationalQueryCompilationContext.
We can then use RelationalQueryMetadataExtractingExpressionVisitor which is an expression visitor that specifically looks for the AsSplit configuration.
We pass the context and then visit the query, this will set the context to various values.


public static bool IsSplitQuery(IQueryable query, DbContext context)
{
    var infra = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>)context);
    var compContext = (RelationalQueryCompilationContext)infra.GetService<IQueryCompilationContextFactory>().Create(false);
    RelationalQueryMetadataExtractingExpressionVisitor visitor = new(compContext);
    visitor.Visit(query.Expression);
    return compContext.QuerySplittingBehavior == QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery;
}

dotnetfiddle
You need the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational NuGet package, and the following namespaces:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;


my kingdom for not-using-'var' with ~learning examples.  If you add "using" statements and replace "var"'s, I will upvote this useful answer.

I'm not saying "using" "code blocks".  "using"'s like "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;"

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not feel really comfortable using internal functions that can be removed without any warning and further complicate future code maintenance. Also, I'm still getting the same problem which I mentioned in comment to @Charlieface's answer.

Sorry what problem?

There is .ToQueryString() method on your LINQ queries where you can see the underlying query generated by EF Core

I'm aware of ToQueryString() method, however it does not give full information whether query was translated to one or multiple SQL queryes. It gives the following disclamer for all queryes containing AsSplitQuery() method: This LINQ query is being executed in split-query mode, and the SQL shown is for the first query to be executed. Additional queries may also be executed depending on the results of the first query

Also, I would need to know that information in runtime of my application, and searching for given string inside ToQueryString() result doesn't seem as a very clean solution.
